# C++ Own Iterator

Tags: c++, linked-list, iterator

i have a little problem with my c++ code. I have linked list (picture below) and i need to make a iterator for my own (school work)..

[list http://www.attanon.eu/list.png](http://www.attanon.eu/list.png)

I have in list variables with head, last and actual node in list.

My class iterator is this

```
class iterator
{
    Node* _node;
public:
    iterator(Node* node) : _node(node){}
    ~iterator(){ _node = nullptr; }

    iterator& operator=(const iterator& other)
    {
        _node = other._node;
        return *this;
    }
    bool operator==(const iterator& other)
    {
        if (_node == nullptr || other._node == nullptr)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return _node->_data == other._node->_data;
        }
    }
    bool operator!=(const iterator& other)
    {
        if (_node == nullptr || other._node == nullptr)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return _node->_data != other._node->_data;
        }
    }

    iterator& operator++() // prefix
    {
        if (_node != nullptr)
        {
            _node = _node->_next;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    iterator operator++(int) // postfix
    {
        iterator temp(*this);
        ++(*this);
        return temp;
    }
    T& operator*() // dereference
    {
        return _node->_data;
    }
    T* operator->() // šipková notace
    {
        return &*(List<T>::iterator)*this;
    }
};
```

And I need to make method begin and end for iterate throught the list.

I try it this way, but with this implementation i don't get the last node of list.

```
iterator begin()
{
    return iterator(_head);
}

iterator end()
{
    return iterator(_last);
}
```

Can anyone help me how to make this two methods?

P.S. Sorry for my english, it's not good I know.

Thanks for help

Edited:

My Node class is this

```
class Node
{
public: 
    T _data;
    Node* _next;
};
```

I used this for cycle for testing..

```
for (List<int>::iterator it = list->begin(); it != list->end(); it++)
{
    std::cout << *it << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The end iterator should be to the "past-the-end" element, not the actual last element. So you should really have:

```
iterator end()
{
    return iterator(nullptr);
}
```

and then implement `operator==` as:

```
bool operator==(const iterator& other) { return _node == other._node; }
bool operator!=(const iterator& other) { !((*this) == other); }
```

to make it accept `nullptr`.

Comment: I found this way, but with this i need to probably rework my iterator operators, because it isn't showing anythink.

Comment: @JAttanonRadar What do you mean by "it isn't showing anything"?

Comment: If i use the testing function, it isn't print the data in list..

Comment: And if i use your implementation operators it's looped.

Comment: @JAttanonRadar Please, [go here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/), paste your entire code (including `main`) and share the link to it here.

Comment: @JAttanonRadar It seem to be [working just fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dacf66dba8bde0e8).

Comment: It is looped.. I need to print only once.. so 5, 20, 22.. not again again and again.

Comment: Any help how stop this loop after one loop? I can't figure out.

Comment: @JAttanonRadar When you are pushing a new element you are doing: `_last->_next = _head;`. This will create a circular list and will therefore loop forever. The last element's `_next` should be `nullptr`.

Comment: That's problem, because my list need to be circular list, it's in task from teacher.

Comment: @JAttanonRadar then in a circular list there's no `end`.

Comment: yes, that's a specification of Cyclic Linked List. Why we have to use that list i don't know, but we have to. For a loop i can use cycle to `_last`, but for the iterator i don't know

Comment: @JAttanonRadar It doesn't make sense for a circular list to have an `end` iterator. It simply doesn't have an `end`.

Comment: I have to do it this way.. Maybe i found the way, i have private bool variable which indicates if the first node pass. And in `end` method i pass `_head`.. I have to add in increment set of the variable bool variable.